# Spring - Select controller based on a flag

Tags: spring, controllers

**Problem definition**
I have a link that points to say myapp/doStuff

Currently I have a Spring controller to handle this request.. say doStuffOld

However now with a new project I need to do the following
1. Add a date dependent flag - dateFlag (false if date< 10-Sep else true)
2. Create a new controller doStuffNew
3. For the same url (myapp/doStuff) I need use doStuffOld if dateFlag is false else use doStuffNew

What is the best way to achieve this in spring.
Note: The URL comes dynamically from outside the application and cannot be altered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [request forwarding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

```
boolean dateFlag = Boolean.getBoolean(request.getParameter("dateFlag")); //Get the dateFlag value in the `doStuff` handler method

if(dateFlag){
    request.getRequestDispatcher("doStuffOld").forward(request, response);
    return null;
}
```

In your `myapp/doStuff` handler you can check for the flag and forward the request to new url(`doStuffOld`), you can use the [params](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29) option.

Another solution if [RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) is used and you can do not want the old handler to be called `doOldStuff`

```
@RequestMapping(value="doStuff", params="dateFlag=true")
public ModelAndView doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ....
}

@RequestMapping(value="doStuff", params="dateFlag=false")
public ModelAndView doOldStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ....
}
```

Comment: I agree I could do that, however the client has a strict requirement that only the correct controller should be invoked. So basically no redirection from 1 controller to another. I am trying to figure out the feasibility of this

Comment: @user1812652 is it required that the old handler must be called `doOldStuff`

Comment: and which is the spring version used also are you using `RequestMapping` annotation to map the request handlers

Comment: Based on the flag one of the 2 handlers need to be called for the same url. I used old and new terms in my desc just to differentiate. These 2 controllers have different logic. Also Spring 3+ is used and so I can use Request mapping annotation

Comment: Thanks.. This makes more sense. Now since the url is dynamically rendered (application does not create this url) and the dateFlag determination is in a Util.java file. How do you suggest I integrate this in the params logic?

Comment: It is a web service call that renders the url through a custom tld

Comment: Also the client is very particular about clean code with no unnecessary manipulations. I am trying to figure out if spring gives something out of the box for such situations or if a hack of some kind is inevitable

Comment: Sorry I do not have expertise in tld

Comment: I think this is as clean as it can get

Comment: No Problems dude.. you did help alot